# CD4521 frequency divider warms up while RESET is HIGH

Tags: power, digital-logic, cmos, thermal, frequency-divider

I have a peculiar problem involving the [CD4521 frequency divider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZMcO.jpg) of which I use two in a redundant configuration as shown in my schematic snippet below:

[image: redundant CMOS timer]

I noticed that while the devices are held inactive (RESET is HIGH), they both become very warm. I took some measurements with a K-Type thermocouple and established **49°C** when inactive and **29°C** when active (with a PCB substrate temp. of **21°C**) in the middle of the chips' SOIC packages. The temperature is the same between the two units and they both operate reliably (so far).

I'm confused. I don't have floating inputs, the input impedance of the NAND XOR is high enough to not draw significant current and I tried increasing the RST pull-ups to 100kΩ with no effect. What could be causing this? I wasn't born with CD-series logic in hand so maybe I'm missing out something obvious...

Below is the relevant part of my PCB layout - your wisdom will be much appreciated!

[image]

---

### Update

I cut the trace grounding Pin 7 as suggested by *brhans* & *SamGibson* and the operational temperatures returned to normal!

Also, I varnished over the cut with nail polish to prevent accidental contact due to oxide growth.

[image: close up of of pin7]

Comment: Pin 7 is an output. You shouldn't be grounding it.

Comment: The amount of stuff one can overlook when staring at his/her own creation for a prolonged period of time is astounding. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the excellent comment from *brhans*, the problem is the connection of pin 7 to Gnd (V<sub>SS</sub> on your schematic). The internal logic diagram for the 4521 IC explains the problem - see diagram below.

**Summary**: When you drive `RESET` (pin 2) active (High), the IC tries to make `Y1 (OUT1)` (pin 7) **High** - but you have connected pin 7 to **Gnd** on your PCB.

Therefore you are effectively trying to cause a short-circuit at pin 7 of the IC, limited mainly by the IC's output driver current capability. It is possible that this has already damaged the IC, to a greater or lesser extent. If you are lucky, any internal damage has been confined to the driver for pin 7, which you aren't using. (A different 4521 IC datasheet mentions an absolute maximum output current of 10mA, which you will be exceeding.)

**Solution**: Fix your schematic & PCB to disconnect the unused output on pin 7. It is normal to leave unused *outputs* unconnected, not connect them to Gnd. Also, as I mentioned, these ICs might already have been partially damaged, and require replacement if you want to be confident of their future behaviour and reliability.

Again, kudos to *brhans* for spotting the problem first.

---

[image: Edited image from page 2 of TI CD4521B datasheet]

I've edited the original image from the TI datasheet that you linked, to remove extraneous parts. Note that the TI datasheet is a scan of an earlier Harris Semiconductor datasheet, so it does not have the high resolution of typical modern datasheets.

The logic gate just after the `RESET` signal is an inverter (the remains of other, removed, signal lines make the inverter symbol a little unclear).

- In normal use, `RESET` is Low, `IN1` (pin 9) is also Low (as it is connected to Gnd on your PCB). Therefore, after each going through an inverter, the two inputs to the NAND gate in the diagram are both High, and its output is Low. After two more inverters, you see that `OUT1` (pin 7) is also driven Low.

  Since the logic Low driven on pin 7 is not exactly zero volts, there will be an extra (unplanned) current from pin 7 to Gnd. However, this extra current will be less than in the case below.

  This might explain why the ICs are "usually" running at 29°C, on a PCB with a temperature of 21°C.
- When `RESET` is driven High, `IN1` is still (fixed) Low. Following the inverter gate on the `RESET` signal, one input to the NAND gate is now Low. Therefore its output is now High. After those two inverters on the NAND gate output, the IC *tries to* drive `OUT1` (pin 7) *High* but it cannot do that, due to the (very low resistance) connection of pin 7 to Gnd on the PCB.

  That will cause a *significant* current to flow through the IC and also cause its temperature to rise, as you measured. It may also have damaged one or both of these ICs.

---

Slightly clearer internal logic diagrams of the 4521 IC are available in the datasheets from:

- [ON Semiconductor](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC14521B-D.PDF) (see page 7)
- [Nexperia](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/HEF4521B.pdf) (see page 3)

They show the same gate structure between the `RESET`, `IN1` and `OUT1` pins as in the (poorer resolution) TI datasheet, and so they will behave in the same way, when the `RESET` signal is High (active).

Comment: Thank you for the analysis and for taking the effort to prepare such an exhaustive answer! I've looked at that inner circuit diagram many times for various reasons, but I totally overlooked the issue with Pin 7! I have to admit that I like that crusty old scan quite a bit.

I cut some traces and true enough, the temperature is now close to ambient at all times! I'll look out for this issue from now on.